# Why is Spring Cloud called "Cloud"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

Spring Cloud is a framework that helps implementing a **Microservices** architecture (with common patterns and practices, like Runtime Configuration, Tracing, Circuit Breaker, Service Discovery, and so on), but it has nothing to do with "**Cloud**", right?

Microservices and Cloud are a good match when combined, but Spring Cloud helps with microservices, not with cloud. Am I right?

My question is: wouldn't **Spring Microservices** be a better name for **Spring Cloud**?

I don't want to change its name, I just want to be sure that I understand the framework correctly.

For the record, "**Spring Cloud Netflix**" or "**Spring Cloud Amazon**" would be well named, because they do help with the integration of those specific Cloud platforms.

Comment: Why is Spring called "Spring"? It has nothing to do with springs, right?

Comment: Don't get hung up on a name. You have read the overview and it seems like you have understood it. Don't second guess yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, probably people from Pivotal responsible for naming can give you the good answer, I can only speculate.

In my understanding, Spring Cloud is set of tools that allow (mainly spring boot driven) application to be written in "Cloud Native" way. When you run in the cloud, it makes sense to protect the application with Circuit breaker, to use service discovery in a way that scaling out the various parts of the system will work seamlessly, and so on and forth.

Now, spring boot application don't necessarily run in the cloud, in fact its possible to run spring boot app on your "personal" (on-premise) server.

Spring boot applications are not restricted to run microservices as well, its possible to run monoliths with spring boot as well. In fact there are many monolith application that use spring under the hood.

Now, can you take tools from spring cloud and use them for applications not running in the cloud? Yes of course you can. Can you benefit from these tools? Probably yes, but not so much if you run one microservice on one on-premise server (I'm exaggerating but still).

Probably (again a speculation) it will be correct to say that the more your environment "resembles" the cloud (public cloud, private or hybrid) - the more benefits you'll see from using these tools. Hence the name :)

Comment: I don't agree with "Spring Cloud is set of tools that allow application to be written in Cloud Native way". Microservices is an architectural style that is well suited to Cloud Native applications, and Spring Cloud helps building microservices architectures...

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring Cloud](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) library is a general-purpose tool for the implementation of distributed systems.

> Spring Cloud provides tools for developers to quickly build some of the common patterns in distributed systems (e.g. configuration management, service discovery, circuit breakers, intelligent routing, micro-proxy, control bus, one-time tokens, global locks, leadership election, distributed sessions, cluster state)

The microservice architecture is not necessarily built on cloud technologies, such as Amazon and might be run on the self-hosted servers.

Moreover, it's true that the microservice architecture is based on the "architectural patterns" such as service discovery, API gateway, sidecar-proxies etc., however it doesn't mean that it is the **only** architecture that can benefit from these characteristics.

I believe the name Spring Cloud was chosen well since it is focused on the implementation of **distributed systems**.

Comment: It focus on the implementation of distributed systems and thus it should have been called Spring Distributed Systems, but never "Spring Cloud", because it has nothing to do with cloud. Righ? System build with this framework can be deployed in cloud or not, so no point on calling it "Spring Cloud", if I understood well.